Firefox: play video will not start
Video play will not start on mouseenter unless I mouseleave and mouseenter again.
This only happens in Firefox, it works in Chrome and Opera.
This is my code for playing the video:
private async playVideo(): Promise<void> {
  this.htmlVideoElement.muted = true;
  try {
    await this.htmlVideoElement.play();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  } catch (err) { /* empty */ }
}

And actual video element:
<video        
  preload="none"
  class="game-video"
  [src]="game?.backgroundVideo"
  loop
  muted
  playsinline
  #video
></video>

I would like to emphasize that video WORKS but only on second mouseenter event. I think that it might have something to do with user interacting with the document first but not sure how to bypass this...
